# Replace attribute not valid html5 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to replace attribute and set value with jquery

**old html**

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="106" valign="top" style="background: red">
          <p align="center">text</p> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**New HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:106px; background: red;">
          <p style="text-align:center;">text</p> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Just a first idea: You could get the attr() value from the elements, remove the attributes with .removeAttr() and re-insert it with .css(). I think that would work, but you'd have to make several checks for all attributes that might be there. And be sure the attributes are the same as todays css. I am also wondering if this can be done easier, especially when dealing with older html and trying to "translate" it to current standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the getAttribute() function to retrieve an attribute's value. So, i'll use `<td width="106" valign="top" style="background: red">` as an example:

```
var style = 'width:' + $('#container td').getAttribute('width') + ';' + $('#container td').getAttribute('style');
$('#container td').attr('style', style);
```

Will result in `<td style="width:106px; background: red;">`. However, this is assuming you only have a single table cell in your table. If you had multiple, you would simply use this concept to apply this method to each cell in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can replace the attributes and set the value for it using jquery :
```

HTML Code :

Give some class name to the tag you want to set the attribute value

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<tr>
    <td class ="table-cell">
      <p class = "text">text</p> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

jquery Code :

While using class name like this (table-cell) it should be converted to Camel casing (tableCell)

```
$(function(){
     $(".tableCell").style.width = "106px";
     $(".tableCell").style.backgroundColor = "red";
     $(".text").style.textAlign = "center";
});
```